# How to use trial and error algorithm to predict the next number in a sequence?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a time series data.  I want to use trial and error algorithms to predict the next number in a variation_sequence. I mean about Trial and error algorithm is using an online learning and where I do not have any more information on the sequence. There is a possibility to use order-n Markov predictor.

But I don't know which algorithm is suitable to order-n Markov predictor? If there is alternative possibility?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time_in_minute = [1, 11, 21, 26, 35, 39]
variation_sequence = [449.48, 553.57, 696.783, 870.133, 1000.4, 1309.1]
plt.plot(time_in_minute, variation_sequence, color='orange')
plt.xlabel('Variation')
plt.ylabel('Time')
plt.title('Variation of data')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Share your `variation` variable value

Comment: @Alderven Could you please check the edited question?

Comment: Please share not png file but variable value to use it in your script

Comment: @Alderven Thank you very much for you help. I am  new with trial and error algorithms. So if I am not confused about your request, the variable value that i want to predict is variation  `variation_sequence = [449.48, 553.57, 696.783, 870.133, 1000.4, 1309.1]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple LinearRegression

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X = [1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010] 
y = [449.48, 553.57, 696.783, 870.133, 1000.4, 1309.1]  
X = np.array(X)
#Reshape since it expects 2D array
X = X.reshape(-1, 1)
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)

X_predict = [2020]
X_predict= np.array(X_predict)
X_predict= X_predict.reshape(-1, 1)
y_predict = model.predict(X_predict)
print y_predict
```

Output

```
[1394.43833333]
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. But When I say  trial and error algorithm, I really mean an online trial and error prediction such as reinforment learning algorthms;

Comment: @Rishi Bansal   we can't apply supervised learning with time series data. It can not be an efficient way.